# Exact solutions of $x$ in $\cos x(\pi -1)=\cos x\pi$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I want to find an exact solution for $x>0$ which solves the following equation

$$\cos x(\pi -1)=\cos   x\pi$$

Mathematica gives an answer $x=\frac{4 \pi  c_1}{2 \pi -1},c_1\in\mathbb{N}$, but when I substitute this value, say for $c_1=1$, then $\cos x(\pi -1)-\cos   x\pi$ is very close to zero, but not exactly zero.

Then, can I use $x=\frac{4 \pi  c_1}{2 \pi -1},c_1\in\mathbb{N}$ as an exact solution of the given equation?

Comment: $\cos x(\pi -1)-\cos   x\pi$ is exactly zero. Your calculator is not evaluating it as zero because of rounding errors.

Comment: @TonyK How it is zero?

Comment: I meant when $x=\frac{4\pi}{2\pi-1}$. You get an expression of the form $\cos(2\pi+\xi)-\cos(2\pi-\xi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use
$$\cos\alpha-\cos\beta = 2\cdot\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \cdot\sin\frac{\beta-\alpha}2$$